# Plugging Windows 8.1 tablet into Windows 8.1 Laptop dangerous?

Tags: windows-8, usb, cable, data-transfer

I have a windows 8.1 tablet (Asus Vivotab note 8), and I would like to transfer files from my laptop to the tablet. I know that it is dangerous to use double male-ended USB cables to connect two computers together, but I would like to know if the same principle applies in this case, using the charging cord, or a data transfer cord such as one supplied with a smartphone such as a Lumia. Is it safe to connect two computers via USB this way, and would it work for data transfers?

Comment: Yes; just use connect both to the same network and transfer the files that way

Comment: How is this true? "I know that it is dangerous to use double male-ended USB cables to connect two computers together"

Comment: @Ramhound please do some research/double-checking before giving out dangerous advice.

Comment: @misha256, Ramhound said connect to the same network, I think you need to do some research/double-checking.

Comment: @Gaurav Joseph, Ramhound's comment appears to suggest *Yes* to the OP's question.

Comment: @Xavierjazz The danger exists when using a Type-A to Type-A connection. http://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful!

It all depends on whether one of your two devices supports *USB On-The-Go*:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go

If neither device supports this standard (on the ports you're intending to connect together), then your plan won't work and you risk damaging your devices.

The good news is (quoting the above Wikipedia article):

> Non-OTG compliant devices are not allowed to use the micro-AB receptacle, due to power supply shorting hazards

So long as one of your devices has a micro-AB connector, you're perfectly safe. However, your devices might not support what you're trying to do anyway.

As far as I know you would need to obtain special software, compatible with Windows 8.1, to perform the file transfers over USB. This is not something that a Windows tablet or Windows 8.1 supports natively.

You might want to consider copying files from one device to a USB Key / Hard Drive, then copy from that to the second device. This is by far the easiest and least technical solution. You could also set up a wireless LAN and enabling file sharing, or use Bluetooth (if both devices have it).

Comment: How do I know if it supports OTG? I have found an OTG adapter that allows me to plug in peripherals, but that's not the same as file transfers, is it?

Comment: See if you can find the manual or specifications (should be easy online), or ask the manufacturer directly via their support. You're right, a physical connection between the two devices doesn't mean you'll be able to transfer files. Without some kind of special software, the devices won't know where to look for files or *how* to actually transfer them. I don't mean to dissuade you from your plan but do seriously consider copying files over a real network (LAN) or using a USB key/drive.

Comment: I'm asking more out of curiosity than practicality, mostly because for some reason, I can't send files by bluetooth from my laptop, as it doesn't see the tablet for some reason, and it messes with the Wi-Fi for yet more unknown reasons and updating the drivers bizarrely makes the problem even worse. The files I'm sending are small enough to be synced by OneDrive as well. Thanks for your advice though, I'll use your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SD card. Put it into a Android tablet/smartphone or any other davice that support it. Then, use normal microUSB cable and trnsfer files to SD card. Then, just put card into Windows tablet.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same tablet. Bluetooth takes forever to load one file, do not try multiples. It is the tablet losing the file, I spent several hours until I saw a gentleman who stated he work around the file lose by loading them to NoteBook on the tablet, I was try to send Music, so I quit before I became angry.
The Asus Vivo 8 tablet will accept/support “USB On-the-Go.” that's why I ended up here.
I am finding a OTG at Amazon [http://www.amazon.com/Micro-USB-Data-Transfer-connecting-compatible-Accessory/dp/1059983354](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1059983354)   List Price:  $29.99
Price:  $9.77 & FREE Shipping 
So I'm probably going to buy one soon.
PS. Read the comments, the tablet cannot be charged, and data transferred at the same time, it is a device issue.

So it seems you load the files to your thumb/flash drive from your computer (any Windows OS 8.1 to 8.1 is good), then stick the thumb/flash drive in the opposite end of the OTG cable from the end you stick in the Tablet, and download your files using the Flash drive's driver to the tablet.

The tablet even with 8.1 has limitations, and this is one.